# Bootstrap. How to add multiple add affix attribute?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap Affix like this :

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="220">
```

And i add this css for fix the position when affix is triggered :

```
.affix {
        position: fixed; 
        top: 20px; 
        z-index:1;
        margin-left: auto ; 
        margin-right: auto ;
    }
```

Is it possible to use the Affix on several Dom element and affect a different css, something like this :

```
<div data-spy="affix2" data-offset-top="220">
.affix2 {
            position: fixed; 
            top: 50px; 
            z-index:1;
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make specifiers for the 2 divs..

HTML

```
<div id="affix1" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="220">..</div>
<div id="affix2" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="220">..</div>
```

CSS

```
#affix1.affix {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 50px; 
    z-index:1;
}

#affix2.affix {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 200px; 
    z-index:1;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://bootply.com/63178